# Getting the name of the user who executed the Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I know this can be done in code (C#) by using `WindowsIdentity`, but is there a way to do this within the SP itself?

I tried using the `USER` function but it's returning **dbo** instead of the name. Is this because the user is the owner of the database? If that's so, how can I get the db owner's login name?

EDIT:

The application that executes the SP uses the **sa** user account, so if I use `SYSTEM_USER`, the returned value is **sa**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SYSTEM_USER
```

Will return name of user which excecute code in SQL. More in this [aricle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx)

If SQL server service work from **sa** there is no way to get (windows) username from SQL Server side. I suppose it is security issue. Most information about connection to your SQL Server you may get from table `sys.dm_exec_connections`. There are stored IP addreses and port s and other useful things for existings connections.